# No insights data returning from Ads Insights API (/insights)

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-rest-api

[Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) returning following get request

```
act_396592**/insights?fields=actions
```

AS

```
{
"data": [
        ]
}
```

I have also tried using ad id and time range

```
/6072038816***/insights?fields=impressions&since=2017-08-01&until=2017-08-10
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mWRC.png)

Note: This account has enough ads. I have taken ads_read permission.

Comment: You might also need `ads_management ` permission for `/insights` to work correctly. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup

Comment: It's confusing. I'm not supposed to manage ads. I need just Insights data. According to [Ad Insights quickstart doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api/getting-started) "**The Ads Insights API provides API access for reporting and analytics purposes. When exclusively using the Ad Insights API, request the ads_read permission.**"
BTW,  i tried that. not working with ads_management permission.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
act_396592**/insights
```

Above Request didn't work, because Facebook by default shows **last 30 days** insights [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/). If the ad wasn't active within last 30 days then empty data returns.

```
/6072038816***/insights?fields=impressions&since=2017-08-01&until=2017-08-10
```

Above request did't work, because parameters are wrong. I don't know why it didn't throw any error. Its indeed confusing.
The one of correct ways is, using **time_range**

```
/6072038816***/insights?fields=impressions&time_range={'since':'2017-08-01','until':'2017-08-10'}
```

or using **date_preset**

```
/insights?fields=reach&date_preset=lifetime
```

Comment: The longest `date_preset` is now called `maximum` instead of `lifetime`, see [parameters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v17.0)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: the default value for `date_preset` of 'last_30d' is particularly deceitful when you retrieve insights as an edge for e.g. ads or campaigns and can be the cause for not receiving any Ads Insights.

This only returns insights for ads active in the last 30 days:
`<ad account id>/ads?fields=name,id,created_time,insights{impressions,cost_per_unique_click}`
All other ads are retrieved as well, but without Insights.

To include all Ads Insights, use `.date_preset(lifetime)`:
`<ad account id>/ads?fields=name,id,created_time,insights.date_preset(lifetime){impressions,cost_per_unique_click}`

Comment: The longest `date_preset` is now called `maximum` instead of `lifetime`, see [parameters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v17.0)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for ads, there are times when you will not be able to retrieve data via *Insights*. This is particularly true for ads that have been edited. This is a side-effect of an improvement that was made to allow feedback from posts to be carried over to updated ads.

This section (taken from the source mentioned below) explicitly mentions potentially losing access to Insights:

> Once we carry social feedback after you edit an ad, the new ad's post
>   and the old post share social feedback. This relationship results in
>   other limitations. Once you edit an ad, you cannot:
>
> - Publish or schedule to publish new or old ad posts
> - ***Retrieve post insights for old or new ad posts***
> - Reuse old or new ad posts Boost old or new ad posts
> - Read old or new ad posts at /promotable_posts

I encourage you to read the full blog post available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2017/07/18/transfering-reactions/).

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2017/07/18/transfering-reactions/

Comment: This blog post is about edited ads, a specific scenario where things can be go wrong. 
But my all ads are not edited.

Comment: Have you tried the Marketing API?  

There's indeed mention of `Developers usually request these permissions for this endpoint:

- ads_management
- ads_read`

Comment: Yes. I tried that too, though i need only ads insight data, [Ads Insights doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api/getting-started)